# Abstract algebra and programming languages

Tags: reference-request, programming-languages, logic, computer-algebra

Quite often, I stumble upon abstract algebra concepts like initial algebra, free algebra, and similar while reading papers on programming languages. For instance, in papers on algebraic data types, monads, separation logic, models of polymorphic lambda calculus, etc.

Where can I find materials that will introduce me to such concepts, i.e., ones that are related to programming languages and logics? Hopefully, the number of such materials would be small.

Comment: You need to be more specific. For example, give a couple of examples with context.

Comment: @D.W. Sure. But the question isn't asking for that.

Comment: @Raphael It's hard for a beginner to be more specific. The question asks for introductory texts that cover the listed topics and others that the asker is likely to come across. The asker doesn't know what other topics they will come across in the future so can't specify what those would be. This seems entirely reasonable to me. A good answer could be something like "X and Y introduce initial algebras, free algebras and the material you'll need to understand those. Before long, you'll probably also come across A, B and C, too, which are explained in Y and Z."

Comment: I do not remember what books would be most appropriate for a painless introduction. My best recommendation is to ignore Wikipedia. Articles on these topics address people who have to be knowledgeable enough not to need the wikipedia articles. I am not sure what is the technical name for such a waste of time. These concepts are well defined with category theory, but there are more elementary and intuitive introductions.

Comment: @D.W. Sure, single reference is probably too much to ask even for basic concepts. I will modify my question.

Comment: @Raphael Sure, I will update my question.

Comment: @babou I agree on your claim on wikipedia. I tried wikipedia but recursed too much while learning more basic concepts. That is why opened this question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Initial algebras and free algebras are basic concepts of category theory. Thus
you may try the first chapters of [1] (in particular Section 2.2 Functional programming languages as categories) or the books [2] or [3].

[1] [Category Theory for Computing Science](http://www.math.mcgill.ca/triples/Barr-Wells-ctcs.pdf) by Michael Barr and Charles Wells

[2] [Basic Category Theory for Computer Scientists](http://mitpress.mit.edu/books/basic-category-theory-computer-scientists)
by Benjamin C. Pierce.

[3] [A taste of category theory for computer scientists](http://repository.cmu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2846&context=compsci) by Benjamin C. Pierce.